# How to correctly setup the connection string to availability group for legacy app

Tags: c#, sql-server, legacy, sqlclient, availability-group

Imagine you have the following scenario:

- A .net framework 2.0 legacy client app.
- An SQL Server 2016 Always On Availability Group.

How the connection string should be?

I can think on two options:

- Specify the availability group listener name as the `Data Source`.
- Specify the primary replica as the `Data Source` and secondary replica as the `Failover Partner`

Which one should I use to get high availability and automatic failover? Other options?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue right now. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can do something like this https://www.dastagirhusain.com/2020/08/how-to-configure-your-availability-group-listener-in-as-net-project.html

Answer (score 8):

By the book is always to use the AG listener. I guess at the moment your connection string looks something like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Failover Partner=myMirrorServerAddress;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;
```

But if you successfully created an AG group, then change the connection string to use the AG listener, it would look something like this:

```
Server=tcp:MyAgListener,1433;Database=Db1;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI; 
MultiSubnetFailover=True
```

Answer (score 0):

documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-ver16 provides a detailed explanation on this.

Example connection string as recommended when we have multiple subnet connections to set MultiSubnetFailover=True.

Server=tcp:AGListener,1433;Database=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultiSubnetFailover=True

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).